# How to handle Alert on Edge Browser while launching via selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

When I try to open edge browser Via Selenium Grid, Edge browser launch successfully but it is showing the below alert on bottom of the edge browser
"something went wrong with your extensions so we had to reinstall them. You will need to turn them on again."
I am not installing any extension in edge browser. But still it throws the alert.
How to handle the alert? Is their any setting available to hide/close the alert

I am running this execution on below configuration
Server : Windows Server 2012
client : Windows 10

Comment: https://ibb.co/SJbFHms Check this link for error screenshot

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and error stack trace

Comment: I need settings require to hide the alerts display on edge browser. I hope it does not relate to script. ex: Turning off auto save password on edge browser, which hide alert "Would you like to save password"

Comment: Selenium Edge does not launch new instance of the browser(Private Window), It handles what you have usual edge. You should manage manually that extension and things will be work for selenium execution.